# Host landing page in Webflow, and dashboard in Vercel using the same domain

Tags: dns, subdomain, vercel, webflow

So let's say my company has a domain abc.com, we want to make sure that marketing and content within the team can manage all the marketing-related pages like the landing page for example via Webflow, while the actual app (dashboard + auth) is hosted via Vercel.

The issue right now is that I don't really have an understanding how I would go about this. The only functional solution that comes to my head is to give the app a different domain like abc.app, which isn't reasonable.

Basically, I'd like to hear how I could go about this. Ideally I'd like it if Vercel could co-exist with Webflow on the same domain without any subdomains or anything.

This is, at the crux of it a DNS problem so I would really love some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just searching for the answer myself, thought I'd come back here to answer now I figured it out.

In your domain provider (for example godaddy) you just need to set a CNAME record like app.abc.com to point to cname.vercel-dns.com.

You can click 'add' in the domains section of vercel (rather than buy or transfer in) and it'll tell you what to do.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. OP wants to deploy at example.com on Vercel, but serve some routes from the Webflow site e.g., example.com/dashboard (Nextjs app), example.com/privacy-policy (Webflow). I know it involves some rewrite/reverse proxy, but now how how it integrates together. Also stuck on this.

Comment: I think this answers OPs question. What's wrong with serving app.abc.com via Vercel and abc.com via Webflow?

Comment: Although it's a valid solution, this doesn't the question. Having subdomain is not what OP looking for.

Comment: This did answer my question, and in the end, what we did was serve Webflow at abc.com and the rest of the app at app.abc.com. The complexity of meddling with proxies and the fact that the way I understood it, I would have to request any given page from both Vercel and Webflow might increase latency was not appealing to me. 

I did mention it would be ideal to not deal with any subdomains, but the alternative is not appealing to me. That is why I selected this answer.

Comment: @CoodleNoodle do you still use app.xxx or did you figure out a way to get everything under xxx.com ?

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon We stuck with the aforementioned method. But my guess is you could now use [Vercel rewrites](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/rewrites) as a reverse proxy of sorts, where app.abc.com would be served at abc.com/app/* and everything else at abc.com/*. 

Goes without saying you have to ensure that there are no conflicting routes.

Comment: Thanks! just yesterday I finished the setup and it works as expected using Vercel rewrites as you mentioned

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon I am going try it this week. Is the main mechanism the CNAME on app.abc.com for cname.vercel-dns.com, and the vercel rewrite is used just so the URL doesn't appear as app.abc.com/dashboard but is instead abc.com/app/dashboard?

Comment: @dbala not sure I followed you. In my case, I set the app domain in Vercel to be abc.com and then created a rewrite rule for whichever page you want to display webflow content instead of the app resolving.
An unrelated thing to consider is the sitemap. You need to have a proper next js app sitemap since you won't be using the webflow default anymore